# Can I use other similarity class?

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I'm trying to configure schema.xml included in blank-example-solr-config.zip. I found the schema.xml has the following line:

```
<similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.LMDirichletSimilarity"/>
```

Is it necessary to use this similarity class or can I use other class such as BM25SimilarityFactory and TFIDFSimilarity?

Answer (score 1):

You're welcome to change the Similarity class as you'd like.  Either of the alternatives you mentioned above would work.

However if you're making use of the Ranker or `/fcselect` endpoint, you may find that using other Similarity classes results in suboptimal results.  They do work with other Similarity implementations, but the best results have been seen with `LMDirichletSimilarity`.

But you're probably in the best position to determine whether that possible tradeoff affects your specific usage.

Comment: Thank you for your help!